# Jquery Flipbook to upload PDFs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam using Builtbywill Flipbook.

```
<div id="mybook">
    <div title="This is a page title"> 
       <img src="image1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div> 
       <img src="image2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div title="This is another title"> 
        <img src="image3.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div> 
      <img src="image4.jpg"/>
    </div>       
    <div> 
       <img src="image5.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
  $(function() {
    $('#mybook').booklet({
        menu: '#custom-menu',
        pageSelector: true
    });
});
```

Instead of using Images, is it possible to directly upload the PDF to the Flipbook using Jquery or some how?Please help me.
I'm using `http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet` plugin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/89) is the issue regarding creating pdf flipbook with turn.js and pdf.js . You will get an example [here](http://www.maxims6n.bget.ru/book2/viewer/viewer.html) . The glue file between pdf.js and turn.js can be found [here](http://www.maxims6n.bget.ru/book2/viewer/viewer.js). Most probably he ***modified*** pdf.js library as stated in the [issue](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/89).So be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks but MaximS's work doesn't curl pages. but turn.j has this feature.

Answer (score 15):

Why not try

Take a look here, pdfjs + turnjs: http://www.maxims6n.bget.ru/pdf_books/demo_21.html

turn.js :http://www.turnjs.com/

pdf.js : http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

jsPDF : http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your own flipbook using jquery.

Register on this website [Link](http://www.fliphtml5.com/free-pdf-to-jquery-flipbook.php) and download the setup and create your own jquery flipbook. Try it.

Comment: Its not free. However, I want to upload PDF and create flipbook myself. I want to integrate this in to the project.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible with [DFlip jQuery Flipbook Plugin](https://jquery.dearflip.com/). You can create a flipbook with just the PDF link, Plus it supports WebGl for 3D.

```
var flipBook;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //when using source from online(make sure the file has CORS access enabled if used in cross domain)
    var pdfFileURL="example-assets/books/alice.pdf";
    var options = {hard:'cover',webgl:true,height: 500, duration: 800};

    flipBook = $("#flipbookContainer").flipBook(pdfFileURL, options);

});
```

With recent improvements PDF Flip-books can be now easily created only with HTML tags. HTML is automatically parsed and flip-books are ready to use.

```
 <div class="_df_button" source="example-assets/books/intro.pdf" id="df_intro_button">Intro Book</div>
 <div class="_df_thumb" source="example-assets/books/intro2.pdf" id="df_intro2_thumb" tags="3d,images" thumb="example-assets/books/thumbs/intro2.jpg">Intro 2</div>
```

Comment: This [plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/dflip-flipbook-jquery-plugin/15834127?ref=deip&clickthrough_id=985096006&redirect_back=true) costs $18, [well spent](https://codecanyon.net/item/dflip-flipbook-jquery-plugin/reviews/15834127) according to the reviews.

Comment: yep reviews sure look promising

Comment: Although they are just bundling turn.js and pdf.js which is kind of like using open source solutions to sell something -- I'm talking for the HTML5 version

Answer (score 1):

With this library you can [convert PDF to flipbook with jquery](https://heyzine.com). It is as simple as including the library and calling the plugin on the links pointing to the pdf files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pdf-to-flipbook.codingfocus.com/release/jquery.pdfflipbook.1.js"></script>

<script>$('a').pdfFlipbook();</script>
```